# Grails run-app command objects not working after upgrade 2.2.1 to 2.3.6

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I reached next problem after upgrade grails 2.2.1 to 2.3.6
I think any of my Command object in controllers not working for example:
I had Command Object like that:

```
@ToString
@grails.validation.Validateable
class ListUserRoleCommand {
    String userId
    User getUser() { User.get(userId) }

    static constraints = {
        userId nullable: false
        user nullable: false
    }
}
```

I had entry in UrlMapping.groovy:

```
"/user/$userId/role"(controller: "userRole", parseRequest: true) { action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"] }
```

That shoud bind request: my-app/user/4324gf54f4f34r3ff/role with command object in controller UserRoleController and 'list' action (I'm sending GET method)
But I getting validation exception on userId.

```
Field error in object 'pl.fissst.invoice.security.ListUserRoleCommand' on field 'userId': rejected value [null]
```

I'm println $params to console and I had correct data:

```
params: [userId:ff808181458ff92401458ff94e150005, action:[GET:list, POST:save], controller:userRole, start:0, end:24, count:25, sort:[:], filter:[:]]
```

I checked other parts in application, and I'm think that other command objects not working too.
I had that entries in Config.groovy:

```
grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false
grails.databinding.trimStrings = false
```

so that isn't problem of empty sting.
Anyone can help ?

EDIT1:

One more think. If I set in Config.groovy:

```
grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = false
```

application starts works almost properly. Now only some commands not work. But If I set grails.databinding.useSpringBinder to true, I think any of command object not wok.

Why partial of command objects stop working ?

EDIT2:

**I noticed that command object has bind partial data.
I noticed too, that this part of data which was binded is comming from post data  , but this part whih is comming  was missed from url (Urlmapping url params like $id)**

EDIT3:
For above:
I looking on a Web, and I found some threads where people says that :

> `parseRequest`

from Urlmapping not work anymore in grils 2.3.x. Is that true ? How can I handle that ?

Comment: I can’t reproduce what you are describing.  This all works as expected in a sample app I just created.  If you file a JIRA at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS and attach a simple sample app we will take a look.